# Return type with generic with bounds

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following code

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

class RequestType
class Read extends RequestType
class Write extends RequestType

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  }

  def dbrequest[T <: RequestType](t: T): Future[T] = {
    val dBRequest = new DBRequest
    t match {
      case r: Read => dBRequest.read(r)
      case w: Write => dBRequest.write(w)
   }
  }
}

class DBRequest {
  def read(r: Read): Future[Read] = {
    Future(r)
  }

  def write(w: Write): Future[Write] = {
   Future(w)
  }
}
```

read and write method return a `Future` of type RequestType. If `T` is bounded and `Future` is covariant, then why is the compiler failing to conform type of `Future[Read]` or `Future[Write]` to `Future[T]`

Comment: You should add the signature of all involved functions (there read and write) if you want to share a complete reproducer, plus paste the error details (`RequestType` should rather be a sealed trait).

Comment: I slightly edited the snippet to make it compile and I see no problem in it: https://gist.github.com/stefanobaghino/36d46d5275647971d63fb8cd0e1fe836 What problem are you experiencing exactly? Could you please paste the error message?

Comment: @stefanobaghino, your mods compile because both `case`s return the same type. The question code doesn't. It would really help if the OP could post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, the read and write methods have a return type of `Future[Read]` and `Future[Write]`

Comment: What's the point of making `dbrequest` take a type parameter? After all, `dbrequest` just pattern matches 2 known cases, you may just make RequestType a sealed trait and define `def dbrequest(t: RequestType)`. Besides, Alexey explained well the technical reason why it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will compile with one small change.

```
def dbrequest[T <: RequestType](t: T): Future[RequestType] = {
```

So why is it that returning `Future[RequestType]` works and returning `Future[T]` doesn't, especially since `T` is bounded the way it is?

Think of it this way: `T` is resolved at compile time. With every invocation of `dbrequest()` the compiler turns `T` into *either* `Read` or `Write`. The `match` statement, on the other hand, is resolved at run time. So from the compiler's perspective the `match` statement returns *both* `Read` and `Write`.

As has been pointed out, you don't really need a type parameter in this code, as presented. The following simplification is equivalent.

```
def dbrequest(t: RequestType): Future[RequestType] = {
```

Answer (score 0):

> If T is bounded and Future is covariant, then why is the compiler failing to conform type of Future[Read] or Future[Write] to Future[T]

Your code would make sense if `T` was guaranteed to be `Read` or `Write`.
But it could `Read with SomeTrait`. Or [a singleton type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052086/what-is-a-singleton-type-exactly) (so even making `RequestType`, `Read` and `Write` sealed wouldn't help). Etc. See my answer to [Returning subclass of parameterized type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44899858/returning-subclass-of-parameterized-type-in-scala/) for a solution (just replace `Output` in that question with `Future`).